# Configure Karma/Jasmine for colorblind people

Tags: karma-jasmine

Is there any way to configure the css for the Jasmine/karma webpage.

I'm having difficulties seeing the differance between the red and green text on the 'Spec List' page. A fail or success icon would be great.