# Changing the pass / fail text color in Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm red / green colourblind so looking at the spec list in Jasmine to see which tests have passed / failed is genuinely a challenge for me...

Is there any way to customise these colors? I've googled and stack overflowed and can't find a good answer. I've looked through the source files as well and couldn't spot a way to do so.

If it makes a difference, I'm working in Angular so Jasmine comes as the default testing framework.

A blue and orange spec list would be heavenly simpler...

(Seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44026063/configure-karma-jasmine-for-colorblind-people) - makes at least *two* of us)